# Error creating EKS cluster - send request failed caused by POST FORBIDDEN

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am provisioning an "air-gapped" EKS cluster. There is no internet access in the VPC so I have also created the following VPC endpoints: `ecr.api`, `ecr.dkr`, `ec2`, `sts`, and `S3` (gateway).

I have checked that NACL allows traffic from AWS S3 CIDRs and all traffic inside the vpc. The security groups are allowing that traffic as well.

I am provisioning this with Terraform Cloud. The errors received are not very descriptive:

`Error creating EKS Cluster: RequestError: send request failed caused by: POST "https://eks.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/clusters": Forbidden`

Not sure what is Forbidden in this case. Is it the access to the EKS control plane?

Update: I can deploy the EKS in the AWS console without a problem. That using the same security group, nacl and roles.

Comment: A guess: you need to define an endpoint for EKS cluster as well?

Comment: @MarkoE what do you mean by endpoint? There is no vpc endpoint available for EKS, just yet.

Comment: What action tried to list clusters specifically? Are you also trying to create the cluster without internet, not just have the cluster itself air gapped?

Comment: This is the response from AWS APIs. It is the error I am receiving in Terraform Cloud. It is sending the request to create the cluster but it looks like AWS never gets the request as there are no developments in the AWS console. Normally the EKS console would show that a cluster deployment has started.

Comment: Using the same security group, nacl, and role I can deploy the EKS in the console. But not working with the Terraform user.

Comment: What policy is attached to terraform user and where your terraform is executed?

Comment: @Morariu What are the users permission when running Terraform? Is it the same user as the one when you are using AWS console?

Comment: a) Can you check for more info in cloudtrail...  cloudtrail -> event history -> eventName =createCluster  

https://<REGION>.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/home?region=<REGION>#/events?EventName=CreateCluster

b)  What permissions has been given to terraform cloud , whether it has clustercreate iam permissions?

Comment: The issue is with TF running on-premise and not having access to EKS.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide valid AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to your Terraform Cloud. These must be associated with valid permissions to perform needed operations to create the cluster.